# IIS Express - set Virtual Directory

Tags: iis, express, visual-studio-2013, cassini

I'm just moving away from cassini (which I liked for various reasons) and am trying to replicate my setup in IIS Express.

With cassini, I could set the virtual directory of the web app I'm, working on.

For example....
when I pressed f5, the web app would launch at `http://localhost:55555/AppVirtualdir`

I can't see any settings for this within Visual Studio 2013.
If I create a virtual directory in applicationhost.config then I can make it serve the pages from the correct URL, but I get some very funny behaviour in Visual Studio (any files I add to the project are added to the physical path of the root, which is the wrong place)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I do not know of anything in VS to do this, but via IIS, you can create, modify, and delete virtual directories on your local machine.  Do you know how to do this? **EDIT** I just saw you were using IIS Express.  Sorry about that question.  My experience is with the bigger version of IIS.

Comment: For the time being, I've reverted to using VS2012. If anyone comes up with a solution then I'd love to hear.